# Python text file manipulation, add delta time to each line in seconds

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python and trying to solve the below:

I have a text file that each line starts like this:

```
<18:12:53.972>
<18:12:53.975>
<18:12:53.975>
<18:12:53.975>  
<18:12:54.008>
```

etc

Instead of above I would like to add the elapsed time in seconds in the beginning of each line, but only if the line starts with '<'.

```
<0.0><18:12:53.972>
<0.003><18:12:53.975>
<0.003><18:12:53.975>
<0.003><18:12:53.975>  
<0.036><18:12:54.008>
```

etc

Here comes a try :-)

```
#import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from sys import argv

#get filename as argument
run, input, output = argv 
#get number of lines for textfile
nr_of_lines = sum(1 for line in open(input))
#read in file
f = open(input)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close

#declarations
do_once = True
time = []
delta_to_list = []
i = 0

#read in and translate all timevalues from logfile to delta time.
while i < nr_of_lines:
    i += 1
    if lines[i-1].startswith('<'):
        get_lines = lines[i-1]      #get one line
        get_time = (get_lines[1:13]) #get the time from that line
        h = int(get_time[0:2])
        m = int(get_time[3:5])
        s = int(get_time[6:8])
        ms = int(get_time[9:13])
        time = timedelta(hours = h, minutes = m, seconds = s, microseconds = 0, milliseconds = ms)
        sec_time = time.seconds + (ms/1000)
        if do_once:
            start_value = sec_time
            do_once = False
        delta = float("{0:.3f}".format(sec_time - start_value))
        delta_to_list.append(delta)

#write back values to logfile.
k=0
s = str(delta_to_list[k])
with open(output, 'w') as out_file:
    with open(input, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if line.startswith('<'):
                s = str(delta_to_list[k])
                out_file.write("<" + s + ">" + line)
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
            k += 1
```

As it is now, it works fine, but the last two lines is not written to the new file. It says: "s = str(delta_to_list[k]) IndexError: list index out of range.

At first I would like to get my code working, and second a suggestions for improvements. Thank you!

Comment: is this possible in python? Yes

Comment: Of course it's possible. And in fact it's quite easy. You could check the [total_seconds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) function in datetime module

Comment: And ? What's your question exactly ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @KlausD. I added some code. Thanks

Comment: @Chaker. Thanks I have tried that, works nicely, I can not get the code to work though.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. I added the code I have so far. Thanks

Comment: @Matrilx I assume in your result example, the two last lines should start resp. with 14 and 16 ? (18:12:53 + 12s would give 18:13:05)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Yes, that is correct! 14 and 16 is the correct last lines :-) I edit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point: never read a full file in memory when you don't have too (and specially when you don't know whether you have enough free memory).

Second point: learn to use python's `for` loop and iteration protocol. The way to iterate over a `list` and *any* other iterable is:

```
 for item in some_iterable:
     do_something_with(item)
```

This avoids messing with indexes and getting it wrong ;)

One of the nice things with Python  `file` objects is that they actually are iterables, so to iterate over a file lines, the simplest way is:

```
 for line in my_opened_file:
     do_something_with(line)
```

Here's a simple yet working and mostly pythonic (nb: python 2.7.x) way to write your program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import datetime
import re
import tempfile


def totime(timestr):
    """ returns a datetime object for a "HH:MM:SS" string """

    # we actually need datetime objects for substraction
    # so let's use the first available bogus date

    # notes:
    # `timestr.split(":")` will returns a list `["MM", "HH", "SS]`
    # `map(int, ...)` will apply `int()` on each item
    #    of the sequence (second argument) and return 
    #    the resulting list, ie 
    #    `map(int, "01", "02", "03")` => `[1, 2, 3]`

    return datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, *map(int, timestr.split(":")))

def process(instream, outstream):
    # some may consider that regexps are not that pythonic
    # but as far as I'm concerned it seems like a sensible
    # use case.
    time_re = re.compile("^<(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.")
    first = None

    # iterate over our input stream lines
    for line in instream:
        # should we handle this line at all ?
        # (nb a bit redundant but faster than re.match)
        if not line.startswith("<"):
            continue

        # looks like a candidate, let's try and
        # extract the 'time' value from it
        match = time_re.search(line)
        if not match:
            # starts with '<' BUT not followed by 'HH:MM:SS.' ?
            # unexpected from the sample source but well, we
            # can't do much about it either
            continue

        # retrieve the captured "time" (HH:MM:SS) part
        current = totime(match.group("time"))

        # store the first occurrence so we can
        # compute the elapsed time
        if first is None:
            first = current

        # `(current - first)` yields a `timedelta` object
        # we now just have to retrieve it's `seconds` attribute
        seconds = (current - first).seconds

        # inject the seconds before the line
        # and write the whole thing tou our output stream
        newline = "{}{}".format(seconds, line)
        outstream.write(newline)

def usage(err=None):
    if err:
        print >> sys.stderr, err
    print >> sys.stderr, "usage: python retime.py <filename>"
    # unix standards process exit codes 
    return 2 if err else 0

def main(*args):
    # our entry point... 
    # gets the source filename, process it 
    # (storing the results in a temporary file),
    # and if everything's ok replace the source file
    # by the temporary file.

    try:
        sourcename = args[0]
    except IndexError as e:
        return usage("missing <filename> argument")

    # `delete=False` prevents the tmp file to be
    # deleted on closing.    
    dest = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    with open(sourcename) as source:
        try:
            process(source, dest)
        except Exception as e:
            dest.close()
            os.remove(dest)
            raise

    # ok done
    dest.close()
    os.rename(dest.name, sourcename)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # only execute main() if we are called as a script
    # (so we can also import this file as a module)
    sys.exit(main(*sys.argv[1:]))
```

It gives the expected results on your sample data (running on linux - but it should be ok on any other supported OS afaict).

Note that I wrote it to work like your original code (replace the source file with the processed one), but if it were my code I would instead either explicitely provide a destination filename or as a default write to `sys.stdout` instead (and redirect stdout to another file). The `process` function can deal with any of those solution FWIW - it's only a matter of a couple edits in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I not sure how to get it to work though. Can you look at my updated code? Now it almost work as a starter :-) Thanks

Comment: "I not sure how to get it to work though" well it's fairly documented though... Have you tried using it at all ?